# Black squirrel in France?

Tags: species-identification, mammals, invasive-species

I saw a nearly jet black squirrel in ardeche today,  carolinensis have invaded the UK and Italy, however I didn't find news about their arrival in France. Was that black squirrel really a Canadian species?

Comment: Note that "Black morphs may also occur with Eurasian red squirrels" (Wikipedia). I have personally seen some such exemplars. while they are black they are the (smaller) size of European red squirrels. If you've seen both American and European red squirrels (in real life), it's hard to mistake them due to size differences.

Comment: Yes you are completely right. I have seen some other black morph squirrels which are Eurasian reds and some which are the same color as tree bark from a fairly dark pine tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *Sciurus carolinensis* has been invasive in France, Italy and Switzerland for quite a few years already ([Bertonlino and Genovesi, 2003](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006320702001611)).

Note that the "original" distribution of *S. carolinensis* is over eatern Canada and USA. Not Canada only.